# Open FB page in FB app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-8

From WP8 app I want to open a given Facebook page (profile) in a Facebook app.

I tried:

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("fb://profile/<page id>"));
```

But I just opens Facebook app on my home page. In other words, it behaves as if I typed

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("fb:"));
```

What is a correct way to set a Facebook profile?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("fb:pages?id=<page id>"));
```

Comment: This works? I'm using Windows  Phone 10 on Debug Mode and nothing happens.

Comment: The page ID is the number of the page. Find it at the bottom of the About page of you Facebook page. Like 1104893686188616. It works for me.